# Fail to produce colored boxes around hyperlinks in AMSART

Tags: hyperref

Somebody told me to use the `hyperref` package to produce colored boxes around *\cite*, *\ref*, and *\eqref*. That way, I would have done it like:

> [image]

But in reality, it doesn't work for me:
[image]

Why's that? Please allow me to show you my preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}

\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{CJKutf8,mathpazo,upgreek,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,mathtools,mathabx,physics}
\usepackage{enumerate,nicefrac,relsize}
\usepackage{cases,csquotes}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,decorations.pathreplacing}

\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=red]{hyperref}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{coro}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem*{thm*}{Theorem}
\newtheorem*{prop*}{Proposition}
\newtheorem*{coro*}{Corollary}
\newtheorem*{lem*}{Lemma}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{dfn}[thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{ex}[thm]{Example}
\newtheorem{rem}[thm]{Remark}
\newtheorem{exc}[thm]{Exercise}

\begin{document}
...
\begin{prop}\label{Prop: gtt}
\begin{equation}\label{Eq: gtt}
\pdv{t}g_{ij}=2\varphi h_{ij}
\end{equation}
\end{prop}
...
The proposition below includes some consequences of proposition~\ref{Prop: gtt}, whose derivations are already explicit and complete in \cite[section 7.1]{HP96}. We simply cite them
...
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{HP96} Gerhard Huisken and Alexander Polden,
\textit{Geometric evolution equations for hypersurfaces}, ...
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Doesn't the `hyperref` package go well with the `amsart` documentclass? Thank you for your help!

**Edit.** Sorry, I forgot to mention that I normally work with Texmaker and MiKTeX.

Comment: You're using `colorlinks`, aren' you?

Comment: @egreg Yes...But the box did not show up...

Comment: According to the [`hyperref` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/hyperref-doc.pdf), boxes are removed if you use `colorlinks` to color links.

Comment: I'm very sorry, guys. I know the point now.  Colored boxes cannot reveal themselves in the PDF viewer of Texmaker, but if I open the PDF file directly with, say, Adobe, then I can see those colored boxes. Thank you, folks. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colored boxes are a previewer thing, but they aren't added when the link is already colored.

This is what I see with Skim if I run your document without the `colorlinks` option enabled.

[image]

If however I use Adobe Acrobat, I see

[image]

So you see that *some* previewers add the box (only on screen and not in print) if there is no other mean to see the link; other previewers don't.

If I enable `colorlinks` both previewers show essentially the same

[image]